# fail to create event monitor db2detaildeadlock in aix

Tags: db2, deadlock, aix, monitor, db2-luw

Base on this link, http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21193054 
I am trying to create the event monitor db2detaildeadlock in my db2 database.

I am running the following command:

```
db2 create event monitor db2detaildeadlock for deadlocks with details write to file 'db2detaildeadlock' maxfiles 20 maxfilesize 512 buffersize 17 blocked append autostart
```

But hitting

```
DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0104N  An unexpected token "DB2DETAILDEADLOCK" was found following "etails
write to file".  Expected tokens may include:  "CHAR_STRING_LITERAL".
```

I am running my db2 database in AIX server, is it any other syntax changes on this command?

```
My database server : DB2/AIX64 10.5.9
```

And is there any way to check my event monitor `db2detaildeadlock` is activated or deactivated ? Because I cant see any deadlock log after hitting deadlock.

Comment: Try using a different name - there is a default monitor with the same name. When you created your monitor get rid of the old one avoid having two monitors with the same mission. Personally I would recommend not to write to files but to tables this eases the analytics part a lot.

Comment: Let say if I successfully run this command, then the deadlock log will be log to db2detaildeadlock file? or those 0000001.evt file?

Comment: If you are using Version 10.5 then you should not use information for v9 and v8 (which you see in SWG21193054). Refer to the correct version Knowledge Center for up to date syntax. If you did not already drop the pre-supplied  db2detaildeadlock monitor, then why try to create it?  To *ensure* the event monitor is activated, then explicitly activate it with `db2 set event monitor db2detaildeadlock state=1` (command line action example). This will either succeed, or report warning SQL1615W (already activated).

Comment: Looks like your quotes are being interpreted by the shell; try `db2 "create event monitor evmon_dl for deadlocks with details write to file 'db2detaildeadlock' maxfiles 20 maxfilesize 512 buffersize 17 blocked append autostart"

Answer (score 0):

This SQL will show the state of your event monitors

```
SELECT  SUBSTR(EVMONNAME,1,40) AS EVMON_NAME
,       TARGET_TYPE
,       SUBSTR(OWNER,1,8)        AS OWNER
,       CASE    EVENT_MON_STATE(EVMONNAME)
                WHEN 0 THEN '0 Inactive'
                WHEN 1 THEN '1 Active'
        END                                     AS STATE
FROM SYSCAT.EVENTMONITORS
```